# Political issues in a magical terrarium

Tags: society, geopolitics

Before commenting on the question itself, allow me to contextualize the story:

It all started because of a nuclear war between Atlantis and Lemuria because both continents had different ideologies about the development of other peoples, because while one wanted to maintain a colonialist mentality, the other believed that leaving them "free" would be a better alternative, but neither of them is in fact a villainous or heroic nation as both are to blame both for the genocide and colonization of these minority peoples as well as for the cataclysm that culminated in their ruin.

However, after the cataclysm, groups of survivors split. A part stayed in our world and culminated in the current societies that we know and that are almost totally unaware of these events that took place 24 thousand years ago as well as everything related to magic (this is a matter to comment on another day). While the other part escaped to a terrarium-shaped artificial world inside our planet and use the inner core as the main energy source to keep everything running.

In the beginning, the survivors of both destroyed continents (detail: most were children) managed to maintain an almost harmonious coexistence despite the regrets related to immaturity, internal conflicts and everything related to the children's world, as they swore they would not repeat the same mistakes that the adults of their homelands and they even worked together to try to start over in that vast world, however, as they grew, differences began to arise and the cycle of errors repeated itself to the point that new wars and divisions over millennia culminated in the construction of a wall of great dimensions that divide the continent into two parts like a continental blockade inserted in a political context similar to the cold war with deep religious and ethnic prejudices and both sides of the continent have controversial policies with mixed-races, albinos and people with skin problems (vitiligo).

I wanted to know how to better develop this world in this regard, so to help define, I have one question:

How did these two sides, even though they hated each other deeply and lived in a sort of Apartheid, continued to "interact" with each other to the point where some of them had children?

Comment: This isn't a bad start but you need to limit your question.  Think about something that you have in particular about your world that you need answered.

Comment: Hope this helps to delimit:

How could these two sides, even hating each other deeply and living under a kind of Apartheid, continue to "interact" with each other to the point that some of them have children?

Comment: Good add this two the question

Comment: I wonder whether in the actual South Africa during the days of actual apartheid any mixed race children were born...

Comment: Your current ask seems to be asking us to build your world for you by telling you facts about your world, instead of helping you resolve a specific issue you're having while building your world.

Comment: @AlexP yes there were

Comment: I am not clear about the scenario The survivors are the inside Earth people and the outside Earth people.  Is it these 2 groups that build " of a wall of great dimensions that divide the continent"?  What is the continent?  Or are we talking strictly the inside Earth people fighting, building the wall etc.

Comment: @Willk The survivors dispersed into two groups, the first united with minority peoples outside of Atlantis and Lemuria while the second group composed mostly of children took refuge in a magical terrarium in the interior of our planet. And the continent in question within this terrarium is Prortus which means "promised land"

Comment: @sphennings I'm sorry that you interpreted it that way, I'm still a beginner in this forum so I still don't have much idea of how the discussions happen here but my goal was not to outsource the construction of my world, because what I presented in this post represents only a very little summary of this process and the alternative forms of interaction between the descendants of these survivors is the only question I currently have.

Answer (score 3):

This might be a key: "they swore they would not repeat the same mistakes that the adults of their homelands".

One of the mistakes they failed to not repeat was [biological warfare](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biological_warfare) of the infectious engineered variety. No doubt some viral blueprints and the tech to actualise them remained after the old times.

One side created a virus that targeted only those of pure Atlantean blood, naturally in a tit-for-tat move, the other side reciprocated with a similar virus that was aimed at Lemurians. (That's the story the Atlanteans tell anyhow, Lemurians tell it the other way round).

Because these viruses are rugged and liable to hang around in the environs for indefinite periods, new infections spring-up.

The virus itself: could be lethal, debilitating, disfiguring - maybe there are treatments. Each time an outbreak happens, the virus adapts and creates new variations which resist treatment.

It turns out, the only reliable way to create permanent immunity to the Atlantean scourge is to have at least some Lemurian blood, the Lemurian plague is thwarted by the presence of some Atlantean ancestors. Naturally, you'll find a good proportion of Atlantean medical staff occupying positions in Lemurian hospitals, the same the other way round. Many professions prefer to hire a mix against the occurrence of the disease just to keep their businesses running, municipal staff are always a mix of races to stop services grinding to a halt every winter. Where people mix, they breed. Mission accomplished.

Comment: This is perfect! could be one of the main reasons for there to still be some "interaction" between these two opposite poles and even for there to be improvements in treatments, there could be special permission from governments for student exchanges, which would also end up influencing this miscegenation and also immunity

Comment: I've just realised I stole this from Gene Roddenberry's [Andromeda](https://andromeda.fandom.com/wiki/Abridging_the_Devil%27s_Divide), @SheronSilva . We know the idea can work anyhow :)

Answer (score 2):

1. Deviants.  Even if most of your society leans one way doesn't mean everyone will. There were half European half African children born under apartheid South Africa. People are curious and part of us likes breaking taboos even if it comes at a price.
2. Political Marriage.  Even if they hate each other they know from history the dangers of not living in peace. Assuming that They have some sort of royalty or nobility perhaps they have certain arrangements where certain members of the royalty or nobility marry members of the other royalty or nobility in order to decrease tensions.
3. Poor don't care.  Even in the Segregated south.  At the poorest leave blacks and whites still interacted and even inter married. Usually people looked the other way because nobody cared what trash did even if it was white trash.